# Similarities and differences between negative look head and except

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have the [following regex](https://regex101.com/r/qhLO0Y/1):

```
(?<t>[^:=]*)(:(?<u>[^:=]*))?(:(?<v>[^:=]*))?=(?<value>.*)
```

Its purpose is to take input like `AppSettings:Envionment:Other=Dev` and parse it out.  And it works great for that.

I now need to change it to parse out `AppSettings__Envionment__Other=Dev`.  Replacing the single colon with a double underscore.

The problem with that is that the `^` operator works on one char only.

In searching, I have found that when you need to match on several chars at a time you should use the negative lookahead feature `(?!\_\_)`.   I [tried that out](https://regex101.com/r/63vIPj/1) (temporarily taking out the need for an equal sign):

```
(?<t>(?!\_\_)*)(\_\_(?<u>(?!\_\_)*))?(\_\_(?<v>(?!\_\_)))
```

An input of `AppSettings__Envionment__Other` it did not get the captures right (`t`, `u` and `v` should be the words between the underscores).

Additionally, I still need it to not match on both the double underscore (`__`) and the equals (`=`).  Running full ahead of what I would thing should work (but does not) [I tried this](https://regex101.com/r/eq7sFg/1):

```
(?<t>(?!\_\_)(?!=)*)(\_\_(?<u>(?!\_\_)(?!=)*))?(\_\_(?<v>(?!\_\_)(?!=)*))?=(?<value>.*)
```

But that does not even come close to working.  (It only matches on the equal sign.)

**How can I go from not matching on `:` and `=` to not matching on `__` and `=`?**

And how would you make a statement that uses `^` for several chars equivalent to several negative lookaheads?

UPDATE:

I should have provided more examples of the inputs that I expect to parse.  All of the following need to be parsed by the RegEx:

```
AppSettings__Envionment__Other=Dev
AppSettings__ConnectionString=SomeValue
LogLevel=Debug
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex for `__` string:

```sh
(?<t>.*?)(__(?<u>.*?))?(__(?<v>[^=]*))?=(?<value>.*)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/m0uz8E/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<t>.*?)`: Match 0 or more of any character other than `=` and capture it in group `t` (lazy match)
- `(__(?<u>.*?))?`: *optionally match* `__` followed by 0 or more of any character and capture it in group `u`
- `(__(?<v>[^=]*))?`: *optionally match* `__` followed by 0 or more of any character other than `=` and capture it in group `v`
- `=`: Match a `=`
- `(?<value>.*)`:

---

Another option is to use tempered greedy pattern (a bit longish) like this:

```sh
(?<t>(?:(?!__).)*)(__(?<u>(?:(?!__).)*))?(__(?<v>[^=]*))?=(?<value>.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, to match both `:` and `__` separator patterns use this:

```
/^(?<t>[^:_=]*)(?:[:_]+(?<u>[^:_=]*))?(?:[:_]+(?<v>[^:_=]*))?=(?<value>.*)/gm
```

The trick is to scan over `[:_]+` after the `[^:_=]*` scan.